# How to Dynamically Update A Number From A Database

Tags: javascript, html, database, grails, dynamically-generated

What I mean is say I have a int displayed in a html page called Total. This number represent the total number of entries in the database and is stored in a table. I can access this number and display it as soon as the page is loaded.

But what I am trying to do is dynamically update this every 10 seconds to display the current count of the database.

So far I have been unsuccessful. Here is what I have been trying.

```
   var myVar=setInterval(function () {addtext()}, 1000);

    function addtext() {
    var result = ${remoteFunction(controller:'run',action:'totalindb'           
    document.getElementById('textarea').value += "${dCounter}";
   }
```

But what I get is either "undefined" or the same value the page loaded with.

ps This is using grails.

Answer (score 0):

everything in a textarea is a string, so you can't do it "+= 1".

```
var String = document.getElementById('textarea');
var Number = parseInt(String.value);
Number++; or Number += 1;
```

Comment: That wont work. I want to get the number from the database :)

Comment: Take a look at jQuery ajax, this allows you to run php code every x time in the background. edit: if you want to go really advanced, there also is " websockets ", with nodeJS